# NoSuchMethodError during injection of WebJarAssets controllers

Tags: java, scala, reactjs, playframework-2.5, webjars

I have a bit of a problem where I get a NoSuchMethodError when running my application due to a failure in the initialization of the WebJarAssets resource.
I wish to utilize WebJarAssets as follows in my scala.html files

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "react.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "react-dom.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("jquery", "jquery.js"))'></script>
```

My build.sbt is as follows

```
name := "myApp"
version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
    "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5" withSources(),
    "org.webjars" % "webjars-play_2.11" % "2.4.0-2",
    //"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
    "org.webjars" % "react" % "15.3.1",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "react-dom" % "15.0.1",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.14",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.14",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.1.0",
    "org.apache.pdfbox" % "pdfbox" % "2.0.3",
    "org.webjars" % "highcharts" % "4.2.5",
    "org.webjars" % "material-design-icons" % "3.0.0",
    evolutions,
    "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4.7",
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.5.3"
)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Typesafe Ivy releases", url("https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

fork in run := false
```

As you can see, I've tried a couple of different webjar libraries
The plugin.sbt for my application is as follows

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.12")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")
addSbtPlugin("io.teamscala.sbt" % "sbt-babel" % "1.0.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
//addSbtPlugin("com.github.stonexx.sbt" % "sbt-babeljs" % "1.0.5")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean).
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.0-M2")

//sbt plugin for eclipse
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
```

Upon running the application, I get the following stack trace

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: controllers.AssetsBuilder.<init>(Lplay/api/http/HttpErrorHandler;)V
  at controllers.WebJarAssets.<init>(WebJarAssets.scala:20)
  at controllers.WebJarAssets.class(WebJarAssets.scala:20)
  while locating controllers.WebJarAssets
    for the 10th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:61)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for the 1st parameter of play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:205)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for the 6th parameter of play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:228)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:227)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1028)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:166)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:163)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:163)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: controllers.AssetsBuilder.<init>(Lplay/api/http/HttpErrorHandler;)V
    at controllers.WebJarAssets.<init>(WebJarAssets.scala:20)
    at controllers.WebJarAssets$$FastClassByGuice$$db4380e1.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
```

Any insights as to what may be causing this would be truly helpful.

Comment: not related to your problem, but current PDFBox version is 2.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Play 2.5 so use the following dependency:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0-4"
```

And make sure you have defined a route:

```
GET         /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Thanks I did try that with no luck. In going this way, is it expected that I should inject an instance of contollers.WebJarAssets and pass it as parameter when rendering the view files as well? I ask this not in being lazy about reading the documentation (been spinning my wheels on this for a week) but because there's a deadline fast approaching and I don't want to abandon the tech. That said, as a workaround, I put the necessary files into the public folder and I'm using Assets.at to include them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the injection issue is.  But you can avoid `webjars-play` and use the built-in sbt-web WebJars support: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#WebJars

Comment: Thanks, tried that with no luck. I'm just gonna place the resources in the public folder and reference them using 'Assets.at'